# Which is the supported version of Spring and spring security for JDK 1.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am having a requirement to incorporate spring security into spring project with version - 3.2.13 and JDK 1.6.

1. Which is the supported version of spring security for JDK 1.6 and spring - 3.2.13
2. Is there any other spring version that I can upgrade to keeping JDK 1.6. If yes, which spring security version can I use with it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 4 can be used with Jdk 6 (and 7 and 8 - isn't spring great? ). I guess the spring security 4 as being part of the eco-system is also compatible with JDK 6.

Upgrading might still break your stuff though. Sometimes additional libraries that are used and that come around spring might require higher version. The easiest way would be to try upgrading and do some tests and you will see if that works.

Comment: thankyou for the reply. I didnt quite get the mention about additional libraries. can you please explain.

Comment: That's correct. When you update from Spring Security 3 to 4 will break things. For example the session token creation is different from version 3 to 4 and when you have several applications with different version and a session cache like memcache or redis, the authentication wont work anymore.

Comment: I mean that for additional libraries (not part of Spring but related through dependencies) you might be forced to upgrade if you switch to newer Spring version and that might be a problem. But the easiest way is just try. Spring security 4 should work properly with JDK 6 (I am using that setup right now unfortunatelly).  If you are going through a major refactoring though you might consider upgrading not only spring but also the java version

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I wont be able to upgrade the spring version. So currently I am sticking with Spring Security -3.2.7 which is compatible with spring - 3.2.13. Thank you all for your suggestions. :)